# How does Mordo-838 know that Mordo-616 hates Dr. Strange-616 very much?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, doctor-strange, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

In *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr. Strange-616 battles Mordo-838 on Earth-838 to escape the chamber and
save America Chavez from Scarlet Witch.:

> Mordo 838: I think I'm beginning to understand why **your Mordo
> didn't like you very much!**

How does Mordo-838 know that Mordo-616 hates Dr. Strange-616 very much?

Comment: Because Mordo-838 had access to a dreamwalking Stephen Strange-838 that told him?

Comment: Didn't Strange-616 tell him earlier?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dr. Strange told him that a few moments earlier:

> DR. STRANGE: They're not coming back. And you just cast your vote now to kill your friends. **Not that that ever bothered you before. You know, you hated me where I came from.** And I bet secretly, my brother, you hated me here. You must’ve been so jealous. Do you know what? I bet you were thrilled when you heard I'd been corrupted. Hell, you probably gave me the Darkhold to begin with...
>
> <sub>*Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022)</sub>

Pay particular attention to the dialogue highlighted in bold text. When Strange says "you" there, he doesn't literally mean "you" as in the person he's talking to, i.e. 838 Mordo. What he really means is *the other* you, as in the Mordo from Strange's own universe, i.e. 616 Mordo.

Also note that when Strange uses the word "me" in this scene, he doesn't always literally mean himself either, but is often referring to his 838 counterpart instead.

You can work out which version of himself or Mordo he's referring to at any given time by examining the context of what was said. For example, when he says *"Hell, you probably gave me the Darkhold to begin with,"* he must be referring to the 838 versions of Mordo and Strange, as 838 Strange was said to have turned to the Darkhold when looking for a way to defeat 838 Thanos, whereas 616 Strange never handled any version of that book (at least, not until later in the film).

Below is my full translation of the dialogue quoted above, with the changes I've made highlighted in bold:

> DR. STRANGE: They're not coming back. And you just cast your vote now to kill your friends. Not that that ever bothered **[the other]** you before. You know, **[the other]** you hated me where I came from. And I bet secretly, my brother, you hated **[the other]** me here. You must've been so jealous. Do you know what? I bet you were thrilled when you heard **[the other me had]** been corrupted. Hell, you probably gave **[the other]** me the Darkhold to begin with...